# seekbar not updating textview in Dialog custom layout

Tags: android, seekbar

I have my Layout for a seekbar and a textview that I am using inside a dialog.
When I try to update the textview from the seekbar nothing happens.

I am doing the changes in the onProgressChanged.
Here is my code from the **milage_main.class:**

```
public class milage_spinner extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setProgress(10);
seekBar.setMax(10);

final TextView sbv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driveTime);
final EditText drive_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.runTime);

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
sbv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
drive_time.setText(progress);
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}
});
}
}
```

And here is the Dialog builder in my **MainActiviy.class** that is getting the my layout **milage_seekbar**

```
private Dialog createMilage(){
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.milage_spinner,null);
builder.setView(linearLayout)
.setTitle("Ktd")
.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
dialog.dismiss();
}
})
;
return builder.create();
}
```

And my XML in the layout milage_seekbar looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Large Text"
android:id="@+id/driveTime"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<SeekBar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to make the **onProgressChanged** inside the **Dialog** in my  mainactivity?

Comment: Did you debug you code and check if the **onProgressChanged** method was called?

Comment: Did run debug and its not being called.

Comment: @alexandermogren check answer i edit my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

milage_spinner xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/set_size_help_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please select snowflake size"

        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <SeekBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/size_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Change to Dialog to AlertDialog in java code and call oncreate.

```
 private AlertDialog createMilage() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.milage_spinner, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(layout);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        alertDialog.show();
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.size_seekbar);
        final TextView set_size_help_text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.set_size_help_text);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                set_size_help_text.setText("" + progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        return alertDialog;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Dont work yet. I have a layout that my dialog uses and the layout.xml for that has its own class and its inside that I am running the code. Should I do it some other way?

Comment: @alexandermogren plz edit your question and post full code also explain problem in code...

Comment: I have updated my code and adde hopefully a clearer view of the problem.